# Firebase and google play on different accounts

Tags: firebase, google-play

I want to integrate a Google Play Account to Firebase. In our company only my boss has owner priviledge for the google play account. The account used for firebase and other tools like adsense has administrator priviledges.

Is it possible to integrate the google play account to firebase in this setup?
How would I do this?

Comment: I just started a bounty. It would be nice to have someone from Firebase answer this question.

Comment: Try this link - https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6392038?hl=en

Answer (score 24):

Let's say your **Google Play Account** is **A** and **Firebase Account** is **B**.

1. Login to firebase via B. Go to Project Settings (Gear icon) -> Users and permissions. *Add account A as owner.* Verify the same via mail.
2. Now switch user and login to firebase via A. Select the recently linked app. Go to Project Settings -> Integrations. You'll be now seeing an option to link under Google Play. Go ahead and complete the step.

Comment: Save me a lot of time! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

What you can do is add your boss as an owner of the firebase project, link the accounts using your bosses account and then remove it from the firebase project. This seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

**To link your Firebase project to Google Play:**

1. Sign in to Firebase.
2. Click the Settings icon and select Project Settings.
3. On the Project Settings page, click the Account Linking tab.
4. On the Google Play card, click Link to
   Google Play.
5. If your project is already linked, you'll see Manage linking instead. Else, If you do not have a Google Play Developer account, you can click create an account to create a new one.

Note: Upon linking, each of your Android apps that exists within Google Play will have its production signing certificate SHA1 imported. You will see this in your Project Settings.

Comment: Linking project works fine when both firebase and google play are on the same google account. The question is about doing it when they are on different accounts.